# Fault-tolerant qudit computation: advantage?

Tags: fault-tolerance, quantum-state

What are advantages of a fault-tolerant qudit computation compared with fault-tolerant quantum computation for qubits?

Comment: This is a very broad question, can you maybe narrow it down/add some focus points? Are you interested in implementation overall, of the fault-tolerant parts specifically, or just theoretical advantages based on scaling etc?